# Как реализовать логику поведения скрипта на разных расширениях экрана?

Tags: jquery, css

Суть такова:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="text">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe error corrupti distinctio non numquam, excepturi, doloribus repudiandae harum. Quisquam fugit, quibusdam beatae! Atque velit, pariatur deserunt suscipit ea nisi quis aspernatur autem ex
    cumque? Amet odio consectetur ea iure sint itaque, rem beatae quas? Aspernatur optio molestiae aperiam nostrum natus?</p>
</div>
<div id="text1" style="display:block; text-align:justify;">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora doloremque nostrum magni, ullam nulla dolorum obcaecati excepturi in quis aut quia numquam ad ut laboriosam, aliquam minima, minus mollitia. Vero.</p>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deleniti ea obcaecati laudantium iste, aperiam, nemo quia, atque earum iure nesciunt praesentium fugiat cum error sunt voluptatibus omnis veritatis. Nesciunt accusantium, quibusdam illo. Laudantium
    itaque, quos dicta tempore debitis expedita iusto odio, adipisci atque ullam harum.</p>
</div>
<a href="javascript:look('text1');" id="a-text1" style="color:#9a0b0b;">скрыть</a>

<script>
  function look(t) {
    p = document.getElementById(t);
    l = document.getElementById("a-" + t);
    if (p.style.display == "block") {
      l.innerHTML = "Читать еще";
      p.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      l.innerHTML = "скрыть";
      p.style.display = "block";
    }
  }

</script>
```

есть блок текста и небольшой скрипт, необходимо на экранах больше 768 отображать весь текст без кнопки (скрыть/читать еще), а вот на экранах меньше 768, часть текста скрывать и отображать кнопку: читать далее

У меня скрытие/показ работают, но как это привязать к описанным выше параметрам?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам стоит добавить такой код:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($( window ).width() < 768) {
        $("#text1").hide();
        $("#a-text1").html("показать еще");
        $("#a-text1").show();
    } else {
        $("#a-text1").hide();
        $("#text1").show();
    }
});
```

Если же Вы хотите, чтобы при изменении размера окна тоже скрывалось:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  if($( window ).width() < 768) {
        $("#text1").hide();
        $("#a-text1").html("показать еще");
        $("#a-text1").show();
    } else {
        $("#a-text1").hide();
        $("#text1").show();
    }
});
```

А вообще можно использовать такие штуки, как [twitter bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com)

Comment: все конечно замечательно, но как ваш код связать с моим, выходит конфликт, и на больших экранах текст скрыт по умолчанию...

Comment: @zorro, https://jsfiddle.net/sh1dh3v4/ только Ваша кнопка не работает там.

Comment: все ок работает, огромное спасибо